# Easiest way to show travelled path on gmapping generated map

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, gmapping, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to create and then export a map created with **`gmapping`** along with the path my robot has travelled to a graphic file. Do I need any additional packages for that, or it's just a matter of configuring **`gmapping`**? I'm running gmapping with a modified version of **`laser_scan_matcher`** as odometry source (it also publishes an `\odom` topic, not only a `\tf` from \odom -> \base_link).

Any hints appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29088/easiest-way-to-show-travelled-path-on-gmapping-generated-map/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/28069/how-to-visualize-a-frame-pose-as-a-path). See my answer there for a possible solution to your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-04**:
Thanks. I haven't found this answer before.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-05**:
Thank you very much again. Works like a charm. BTW. I was unable to install hector_slam (hector_common, actually). hector_roscpp_introspections crashes saying: introspection.cpp:225: error: ‘struct boost::filesystem::path’ has no member named ‘native’. Any solutions? Diamondback, Ubuntu 10.04.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-03-05**:
Oh ok, thanks for the heads up, I'll investigate this.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-05**:
Also, I had to increase time ROS waits for /map -> base_link in hector_trajectory_server, trajectoryUpdateTimerCallback to ros::Duration dur (1.5); Otherwise poses container in /trajectory message was mostly empty in my system. In case people are using slower machines, this might be necessary.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-05**:
I would also uncomment ROS_ERROR in the aforementioned method to leave a hint for users struggling with the same issue. But again, thanks for the software - hope constructive comments are always appreciated :).